# How to pass global data in Controller in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, coldfusion, angularjs-scope

I have an application in ***Angularjs*** and ***Coldfusion***.
I saved in **session** data on user thanks to my file ***application.cfc***.
I would like to get these data in each controller for using them in my templates.

I have done this solution but I'm not sure that it's the best way, because I have to write the same  lines in each controler for getting data and injecting them in the templates.

The file **application.cfc**:

```
<cfcomponent output="false" extends="RootApplication">

 ..........................................

    <cffunction name="onRequestStart">

        <cfset admin = 0>
        <cfset viewer = 0>
        <cfset author = 0>

        <!--- Authenication is OK --->

        <cfif isdefined('SESSION.username')>

                    <!--------------- CHECK USER ROLES FROM an external system START --------------->


                    <cfhttp url="https://myComponent" method="get" result="result">
                        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="userName" value="#SESSION.username#">
                    </cfhttp>


                    <cfset SESSION.userRoles = #userProfile.VALUES[1].cedarRoles#>

                    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(SESSION.userRoles)#">
                        <cfswitch expression="#SESSION.userRoles[i].roleLabel#">
                            <cfcase value="ADMINISTRATOR">
                                <cfset admin = "1">
                            </cfcase>
                            <cfcase value="Author">
                                <cfset author = "1">
                            </cfcase>
                            <cfcase value="Viewer">
                                <cfset viewer = "1">
                            </cfcase>                           
                        </cfswitch>
                    </cfloop>
                    <cfset SESSION.adminRole = admin>
                    <cfset SESSION.authorRole = author>
                    <cfset SESSION.viewerRole = viewer>


                    <!--------------- CHECK USER ROLES FROM an external system START --------------->

            </cfif>

         ..........................................

    </cffunction> 

</cfcomponent>
```

My **index.cfm**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="ContactsApp" class="ng-app:ContactsApp" id="ng-app">
    <head>
        ...............................................
    </head>

    <body>
            ...............................................

            <cfif #SESSION.viewerRole# eq 1>
                <ng-view></ng-view>
            <cfelse>

                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <div>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                      You do not have sufficient access rights to access to this section
                    </div>              
                </div>

            </cfif>  
            ...............................................

    </body>
</html>
```

The file **app.j**s:

```
var app=angular.module('ContactsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

// register the interceptor as a service
app.factory('HttpInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope) {
       return {
            // On request success
            request : function(config) {
                // Return the config or wrap it in a promise if blank.
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },

            // On request failure
            requestError : function(rejection) {
                //console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error on the request.  
                // Return the promise rejection.
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },

            // On response success
            response : function(response) {
                //console.log(response); // Contains the data from the response.
                // Return the response or promise.
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },

            // On response failure
            responseError : function(rejection) {
                //console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error.
                //Check whether the intercept param is set in the config array. 
                //If the intercept param is missing or set to true, we display a modal containing the error
                if (typeof rejection.config.intercept === 'undefined' || rejection.config.intercept)
                {
                    //emitting an event to draw a modal using angular bootstrap
                    $rootScope.$emit('errorModal', rejection.data);
                }

                // Return the promise rejection.
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
 }]);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
    }

    // disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';

    // Add the interceptor to the $httpProvider to intercept http calls
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');

    $routeProvider.when('/all-contacts',
    {
      templateUrl: 'template/allContacts.html',
      controller: 'ctrlContacts',       
    })
    .when('/view-contacts/:contactId',
    {
      templateUrl: 'template/viewContact.html',
      controller: 'ctrlViewContacts'
    })  
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/all-contacts'});  
});    


app.controller('ctrlContacts', function ($scope, $timeout, MyTextSearch, ContactService){

    /* GET THE DATA IN SESSION */   
    $scope.adminRole =  adminRole;
    $scope.authorRole = authorRole;
    $scope.viewerRole = viewerRole;

    alert("adminRole: " + adminRole + " -- authorRole: " + authorRole + " -- viewerRole: " + viewerRole );

    ...................................................
});

app.controller('ctrlViewContacts', function ($scope, $routeParams, ContactService, RequestService, ReportService){

    /* GET THE DATA IN SESSION */   
    $scope.adminRole =  adminRole;
    $scope.authorRole = authorRole;
    $scope.viewerRole = viewerRole;

    alert("adminRole: " + adminRole + " -- authorRole: " + authorRole + " -- viewerRole: " + viewerRole );

    ...................................................
});
```

Could you tell me how to improve that for passing these global values in all controlers?
Could you please tell me if it's possible to send variables in controlers with rootscope and how to do that?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Coldfusion but in other frameworks I usually pass variables to AngularJS through the `constant` provider.

So in your header, you can provide the variables like this:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script>
        <cfoutput>
        angular.module('ContactsApp').constant('SESSION_VARS', {
            username: '#SESSION.username#'
        });
        </cfoutput>
    </script>
</head>
```

and in your controllers/components, you can simply inject this constant like such:

```
angular.module('ContactsApp').controller('ContactController', ContactController);
function ContactController(SESSION_VARS){
    this.username = SESSION_VARS.username;
}
```

Whether this is a valid solution in Coldfusion (specifically, inserting the session values into javascript through the `<script>`-tag) I don't know, but I can't see any reason why it shouldn't work. Hope it helps.